# "Invalid settings supplied for scp_executable" error in Ansible Windows .exe install

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-2.x

Why does this:

```
- name: Install Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4
  win_package:
    path: https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F63CCD8-9288-4CC8-B58C-81D109F8F5A3/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe
    arguments: '/q /norestart'
    state: present
    product_id: {aspmvc4}
```

Result in this?

```
amazon-ebs: TASK [Install Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4] **************************************************
amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid settings supplied for scp_executable: Requested option scp_executable was not defined in configuration"}
```

It's happening for both my software installs (the other is an .msi)

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the windows machine? Can you show your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Ansible with Packer in this case and the error turned out to be related to the Ansible connection plugin (WinRM Communicator heading here: https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html) that was missing the definition for scp_executable.

A sample [project]/playbooks/connection_plugins/packer.py can be found here: https://gist.github.com/adarobin/2f02b8b993936233e15d76f6cddb9e00